# How to deploy nodejs app and its static files on php/apache server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, wampserver

I am trying yo run my node.js app on wamp server, but i noticed that the wamp server can not render my styles.css in the public folder, but running the node server on it on can access these files. below is my code. also i wamp server can not to my mongodb, i think that is because i actually my have my mongodb connection file and my routers file in another folder but in the same directory.

please I am new to node.js but i think the the problem is that wamp server is not accessing these file in the directory. please help me solve this problem if you can. it working correctly on localhost:8000, but not on localhost/node(wamp server).

These file include my css, socket.io, route and my mongodb connection.

please if there is an alternative or any a solution please help.

Comment: You say that it works on localhost:8000... I guess you have tried to enter in localhost:8000/node, have you? You need to specify the port unless you are using a proxy. Always

Comment: Am actually using a proxy

Comment: I have edited my apache vconf file